# How to make one face always be on the top of another

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to modeling a male character with a skirt (don't ask) but when I move the bones the leg very often overlaps the skirt... I've done the weight paint to be influenced by the bones around but it seems I have to do something else.

see image below, any ideas?

thanks

[image]

Comment: doesn't the skirt deform at all?

Comment: You could use corrective shape keys and animate them according to the leg movement. Another less accurate way would be to add a shrink wrap modifier with an appropriate offset.

Comment: yeah, I was thinking shirkwrap...